# Tomcat not loading services

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, tomcat7, meta-inf

Does anyone know if the META-INF/services folder gets loaded by Tomcat at all?? I have a war file that defines a few services, all of which run just fine under JBoss but Tomcat seems to ignore them. Any ideas if this is a Tomcat limitation or something else tha I might be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? On older Eclipse versions there's a bug which causes this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312920

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse - Indigo with Tomcat 7.... was this ever fixed and if not is there a way around it?

Comment: It's an >1 year old bug. Indigo is newer than that. To exclude the one and other, does it work when you deploy and run Tomcat standalone? Shutdown and forget Eclipse and just drop WAR in `/webapp` and call `startup.bat` (or `.sh`).

Comment: Nope, same problem... however, the exact same war file with the services work just file in JBoss... If it makes any difference, my services config files are java.sql.Driver and javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer. Any ideas what else I could try?